# CSS background-image does not show

Tags: php, html, css, background-image

My problem is that the background-image of `image123` does not appear. Including a normal `<img src>` works fine, but I need to do it with CSS (since I need to change the background on hover). Does anyone know what the mistake is here?

HTML:

```
<ul class="class1">
      <li class="class2">
           <a class="link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Kategorien</a>
           <ul class="category_container">
    <?php
        echo '<li>
               <a href="index.php?category='.$row['Link'].'&location='.$_GET['location'].'&sort='.$_GET['sort'].'">
                 <span class="image123"></span>
                 <span>'.$row['NameC'].'</span>
               </a>
             </li>';
    ?>
           </ul> 
      </li>
      </ul>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.image123 {
background-image: url(img/category_items/audio.png) no-repeat !important;   
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Thank you!
FYI, this whole `ul` is a dropdown-menu-container.

Comment: are your img folder is under, where your css directory is?

Comment: Is the `img` folder located near to the CSS file? Perhaps you should go UP one level in directory tree by `../`.

Comment: The path should be alright. The image is located under img>category_items>audio.png... @HashemQolami: I have a separate folder for CSS, is that what you meant?

Comment: Put the background-image URL into quotes and use background-position: no-repeat!

Comment: @pbaldauf: same result

Comment: quotes does not matter. If you have your style.css under css directory, and your img directory is in the root for example, then you need to set your path relative to your css directory. try `../img/category_items/audio.png`

Comment: If you have a separate folder for stylesheets, you should note that URLs are relative to the current path, therefore to get reach the img folder you should add `../` before the image address. Also consider @IVIajid's answer.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to write a shorter css, you should write `background:` and so on. not `background-image`:

```
background: url(img/category_items/audio.png) no-repeat !important;
```

and if it didn't work well, remove `!important` and try again.

Comment: @pbaldauf - Quotes are optional!

Comment: @pbaldauf if the `url` contains space, it is Necessary to put the address into qoutes, but now there is no need to do that.

Comment: This line `background-image: url(img/category_items/audio.png) no-repeat !important;` is incorrect. @IVIajid answer is correct. It should be `background`. Even if the path is correct `background-image` won't work with other specifications like `no-repeat`. It's not a path problem (if it is) after this being fixed. And `url` doesn't need quotes. This is a valid answer and not a comment.

Comment: The part about removing `!important` is really strange. How could it improve the odds?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Some of my projects had this problem and it was so Unreasonable. But with removing `!important` it got current! maybe It could be another reason that the image doesn't show.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. Eventially I could fix my problem by using the actual website-path in CSS:

```
background: url('http://website.com/image.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

For css file, the url should be given as it were originating from css folder, ie the folder containing the .css file. Not the page you are on.